# Accessing files from server

Tags: android

I am doing multimedia application, now i am concentrating on to connect Apache web server. I already uploaded some media files in server. I want to access all media file from the server to android device(to client). How to access data from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the URLs of those files on the server, and use that URL. But this way, the files will be public.

For other security reasons, you can have a server side script, which can deliver your audio video content by setting correct MIME type, and your Android app can request that script for files .

Comment: Thank you aman, I tried, its working. Do you know how to make a list view of the media files which is containing in server side. In simple i want to show all my media files from the server in list view format. Do you have any idea??

Comment: Code a server side script on server, which checks the directory containing the videos and returns you the names of video files in any format like JSON/XML. when your android app will request this script, it will get the data, and then display it in listview after parsing it.

If my answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi aman, i tried but i cant accessing data. can you give some useful links for this issue. or if you have any source file pls attach.

Comment: I currently don't have a working example, but if you have your URL like www.myweb.com/videos/myvid.mp4 , and you give this URL to VideoView, it will start playing it.  what is the exception you're getting? what is the URL you're accessing?

In one of the above comment, you said you have tried and its working, in this one, you're saying it isn't.
Is there any difference in your usage between first comment and this one?

Comment: yes of course. in my first comment i used url to play a video, its working. there is no issues on that. now i am trying to list the video. (Ie) getting all videos files from the server and make it in to listview format. As you said previously convert server side file into xml and then implement into listview. i am struck in this particular area. i dont know how to make a xml file from server side. please guide me.. Thank you aman your comments are valuable for me..!!

Comment: Well, I was misconstrued. I didn't asked to build an XML, but create a server side script (in PHP/JSP or in whatever you want) which accesses the video directory on the server, and tells you the names of the videos. are you familiar with server side scripting?

Comment: Well, that would be a simple script. if your client controls the server, ask him to create the script. if you have the control, tell me which Scripting language you're using. are you familia with JSON?

Comment: I am some what familiar with JSP.

Comment: It heavily depends on what scripting language can be used on your webserver. are you in-charge of your webserver? or the client?

Comment: Both side. Some of my friends suggested that to write servlet program, in that i have to maintain JDBC. in database i upload details of the video path. so whenever i request from client, servelet runs the database and respond according to our need. whats your opinion.???

Comment: You just have to get the list of all videos, right? you just hit a URL to the script/servlet and it gives you the list back. if your server is a PHP server then how you'll use JSP/Servlet? similarly, if its a Java Server, then it won't run PHP. so first you need to be sure which server it is. its also regardless if your client has the access to the server. ask your client to create such a script. you have to worry about it only if you have to handle the server too.

Comment: I am using Java server.Hope servelet is the best option. what do you think about my friends suggestion..!!

Comment: Ohho! why aren't you getting me!? are you sure your webserver supports Servlets?

Comment: Cool then.. go ahead with servlet and write a code which accesses the video directory on server, gets the list of files, and gives it to you.

Comment: And since ur problem has been resolved, and this servlet thing was another issue, you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CouchDB or other NoSQL solutions to access data from your mobile application - http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/08/CouchDB-Android